# Excel - Take what is in last filled column and move to a separate column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2013

I have data in multiple rows and the value in the last column needs moved to another new column. So if my data looks like...

`One      |2.     |5
Two.     |The.   |6
Three.   |3.     |`

Then I need it to look like...

One     |2.       |        |5
Two.     |The.     |        |6
Three.   |         |        |3

Comment: Looks like the formatting is off... I would appreciate anyone with a computer able to change it making it more clear :|. My phone doesn't seem able to put the output correctly.

Comment: I don't see a way of doing this through formula but it can easily be achieved through a double VBA loop. If you are looking for a Formula solution only you may want to wait for one of the true formula experts to poke their head in.

Comment: I'm up for whatever!

Answer (score 1):

Before:

[image]

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        nLastColumn = .Columns.Count + .Column - 1
        Columns(nLastColumn).Copy Columns(nLastColumn + 1)
        Columns(nLastColumn).Clear
    End With
End Sub
```

and after:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This achieves exactly what you are after, feel free to probe if you don't understand it:

```
Sub LastClm()

Dim myRng As Range
Dim lRow, lClm, rCnt, cCnt As Integer

lRow = Sheets(4).Cells(Sheets(4).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lClm = Sheets(4).Cells(1, Sheets(4).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'sets the last row regardless of missing information in the first column
Do Until Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(lRow + 1)) = 0
lRow = lRow + 1
Loop

'sets the last column regardless of missing information in the first row
Do Until Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(lClm + 1)) = 0
lClm = lClm + 1
Loop

'Loops through each row from back to front taking the first cell it sees with information in it
For rCnt = 1 To lRow
 For cCnt = lClm To 1 Step -1
 With Sheets(4)
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells(rCnt, cCnt)) = 1 Then
        .Cells(rCnt, lClm + 1).Value = .Cells(rCnt, cCnt)
        .Cells(rCnt, cCnt).ClearContents
        GoTo 1
    End If
 End With
 Next cCnt
1
Next rCnt

End Sub
```